# A2HS: Basic Safari navigation UI for iOS standalone web app

Tags: mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app, a2hs, safari-minimal-ui

I'm trying to display a basic browser UI within Safari (next/back buttons, but no address bar) when displaying a site in standalone mode when adding to the home screen on iOS.

I'm aware that iOS doesn't support the 'minimal-ui' display property within the app manifest file, yet I have seen this capability on other websites, such as Twitter.com which has basic browser chrome when adding to home screen as shown in this screenshot: [Twitter.com in standalone mode with browser chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZXNH.png)

Part of the reason for wanting this is to give users better browsing capabilities, but also to prevent the home bar from covering up content, since my nav is at the bottom of the page. (I know I could detect standalone mode and add extra padding, but I'd prefer a simpler solution).

Is there a way of achieving this? Any help appreciated!